# How to rig a human model with scattered elements over the skin?

Tags: rigging, auto-rig-pro, scatter-objects-addon

I have been trying with no success to skin a human model with complex scattering over the surface. The idea is that the scattered elements follow the movements of the model, staying in the position they belong (:. It is the first time I am doing something like this, and I can say I am pretty much a newbie when it comes to rigging models. My first idea is to animate it after removing the base human model, so I can see just the plants (in a human-like form). But the main objective is to bring this model with the plants to AR.

I scattered the elements using GeoScatter, and the instances were transformed into meshes (I wonder if it is a necessary move). For the rigging, I have been using Auto Rig Pro, but I would be open to another method of rigging / skinning.

Does anyone know how to do it and could give some recommendations?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or you could create the shape of the body and use particles instead? It may be easier

Comment: Yes if you import the object into another software you'll need to convert the particle system to objects, which won't make it necessarily simpler that instanced objects like you're doing it right now. I guess in any case you need to make it as low-poly as possible (a solution could be to use planes with image instead of meshes that have the shapes of leaves. The next thing will be to correctly weight paint

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers. I never did it, I will research. Animate it after is just part of the process. The final objective is to bring this to Augmented Reality, so i not sure if particles would work.

Comment: Yes, my plan is to work with low poly after animate (the animation require more powerful visuals), but still thought I don't know how to add the plants to the skin.

Comment: So maybe first use a particle system, I think you'll have more control than with a scatter tool. Then you'll need to convert the particles to real objects of course. Rigging and weight painting will be another process

Comment: Thank you @moonboots. Yes, soon I will research more about particles as I am pretty interested in this too. (: But at the moment my concern is skinning (rerigging and weight painting) those plant meshes, as the scattering worked pretty well and the instances already tranformed in meshes, so at the end It is pretty much like using particles. 

Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: I don't know auto rig but you need to join all your instances into one object, parent With Automatic Weights, and correct in Weight Paint mode, what difficulty have you met?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help @moonboots. I could finally make it work with AutoRig Pro, it was all about the right sequence of commands and patience cos the operations would take time (and sometimes crashes). But now it works + I learned something more about particles, so that was worth.